# Column names and sorting data in a csv file using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a project where I need to take in 3 csv files, concatenate them into 1 file and then sort the data in that new file by Column 0. I have done the concatenation but I am stuck on assigning column names. And then because I cannot assign column names, I cannot sort, cos I believe you need to pass a column name as an argument to Sort.

You can see there there are 3 lines of code commented out. I can successfully run my code with those commented out, but I get errors when I uncomment them. The data in the 3 csv files is identical format, just like in the commented out colnames line of code below.

My column name error is: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 9 elements"

My sort error is: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sort_values'"

```
def concatenate(indir="C:\\Temp", outfile="C:\\Conc\\A_out.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    #colnames=["Symbol", "Name", "LastSale", "MarketCap", "ADR TSO", "IPOYear", "Sector", "Industry", "Summary Quote"]
    for filename in fileList:
        print("merging " + filename + "...")
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
        #dfList.sort_values(by=['Symbol'], ascending = False)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    #concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
    print("Completed. Your merged file can be found at: " + outfile + "\n")
```

Comment: Given dfList=[] and 
dfList.append(df) you end up with

dfList as a list of dataframes, not a dataframe so you can't use dataframe methods on it

Comment: `concatDf.sort_values(trg_cols,asecnding=False/True)` ? as CoupCoup rightly pointed out you're using a pandas method on a non pandas object which wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sort` instead of `sort_values`? dfList is type `list`, not `DataFrame`.
Also the column name issue is mismatch between the length of colnames and columns in concatDf. You should check `len(colnames)==len(concatDf.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    dfList=[] 
    ...
    dfList.append(df)
```

dfList is a list of dataframes, not a dataframe so of course you can't use dataframe methods like `sort_values` directly on it.

```
for df in dfList:
    df.sort_values(by=['Symbol'], ascending = False)
```

would sort each dataframe in the `dfList`

Answer (score 0):

This was the final solution for that got it working:

```
def concatenate(indir="C:\\Temp", outfile="C:\\Conc\\A_out.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["Symbol", "Name", "LastSale", "MarketCap", "ADR TSO", "IPOYear", "Sector", "Industry", "Summary Quote", " "]
    for filename in fileList:
        print("merging " + filename + "...")
        df=pandas.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList, axis=0)
    concatDf.columns=colnames
    concatDf = concatDf.sort_values(by=["Symbol"], axis=0, ascending=True)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
    print("Completed. Your merged file can be found at: " + outfile + "\n")
```

You can see, 2 line from the end that I needed to assign the sort function to a variable. I could've also used "inplace=True" in the arguments. Either method works.